# Initializing array inside struct

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I'm trying to initialize an array inside a struct, [Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OMSx.png).

I want the array to have the size of row*col.

Here is part of the code:

```
struct tbl{
    int col;
    int row;
    char** elem [col*row];
};


int main(int argc, char** argv){

    int i, row, col;
    col = row = 0;
    bool loop = true;
    char c;     
    col = col/row;  

    table tab;
    tab.row = row;
    tab.col = col;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Poste the code.

Comment: struct declarations define the layout of objects. All the objects need to have the same layout, obviously. How will that work if each one may contain an array of a different size?

Comment: To give more details: Post the code as text directly here, i.e. not as picture and not as external link.

Answer (score 0):

Please not that

- You cannot preset the values of `row` `col` in your code.

To acheive this you need dynamic allocation like this,

```
struct matrix {
    int row_count;
    int col_count;
    int **values;
};

void free_matrix(struct matrix *const M);
int initialize_matrix(struct matrix *const M, int row_count, int col_count);

int initialize_matrix(struct matrix *const M, int row_count, int col_count)
{
    M->values = malloc(sizeof *M->values * row_count);
    if (M->values == NULL)
        return -1;
    M->row_count = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < row_count; ++row) {
        M->values[row] = malloc(sizeof **M->values * col_count);
        // In case of failure to allocate
        // free all rows.
        if (M->values[row] == NULL) {
            free_matrix(M);
        } else {
            M->row_count += 1;
        }
    }
    M->col_count = col_count;
}

void free_matrix(struct matrix *const M)
{
    if (M == NULL)
        return;
    for (int row = 0; row < M->row_count; ++row) {
        free(M->values[row]);
    }
    free(M->values);
}

int main(void)
{
    struct matrix M;
    initialize_matrix(&M);
    // Use the matrix here
    free_matrix(&M);
}
```

You should be extremely careful with the use of `malloc()` and `free()`, you must use it correctly or unexpected things will happen to your program.

Comment: Thanks. I think that i'm going to try it in c++.

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare a struct in that manner.  One thing people have done is to set their array to the end of the struct and then use malloc to leave extra space for the array in the struct.  Something like this:

```
typedef struct {
    int row;
    int col;
    char **elem[];
} table;

void some_func() {
    int row = 5;
    int col = 5;
    table *tab = malloc(sizeof(table) + ((row * col) * sizeof(char **)));
    tab->row = row;
    tab->col = col;
    // now do whatever you need to with your new struct
    // that holds an array of 25 char ** elements
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few of errors in the code. You probably want something posted below. Also, don't divide by zero.

```
struct tbl{
    int col;
    int row;
    // char** elem [col*row]; // can't initialize array size this way
    char** elem;
};


int main(int argc, char** argv){

    int i, row, col;
    col = row = 0;
    bool loop = true;
    char c;           // Unused?      
    col = col/row;    // zero divided by zero? You sure you want that?   

    // table tab;        // not defined correctly, Use next line instead 
    struct tbl tab;   
    tab.row = row;
    tab.col = col;

    tab.elem = malloc(sizeof(char*)*tab.row);
    for (i=0 ; i<tab.row ; i++) {
        tab.elem[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*tab.col);
        /* initalize tab.elem[i] */
    }

    /* ... do stuff */

    // free memory
    for (i=0 ; i<tab.row ; i++) {
        free(tab.elem[i]);
    }
    free(tab.elem);

    return 0;
}
```